# What's the most elegant/idiomatic way to check if a string is in a list?

Tags: java, string, list

In Java, what's the most elegant/idiomatic way to check if a string is in a list?

E.g., if I have `String searchString = "abc"; List<String> myList = ....`, what's Java's equivalent to what I would do in Perl as:

```
my $isStringInList = grep { /^$searchString$/ } @myList;
# or in Perl 5.10+
my $isStringInList = $searchString ~~ @myList;
```

?

Comment: `List.contains` maybe?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - beats me. I'm a Perl developer, not a Java one. If it works the way the name sounds like it works, make it an answer

Comment: [List.contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))?

Comment: Elegant Java, I get it.

Comment: Oh god, these language differences are amazing.

Comment: From this question, now I would want to learn perl.

Comment: @DaveNewton Maybe Java is not elegant but Java Programmers are very elegant :P

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ugh; why? I much prefer things like `list.grep /^searchString/` a la Ruby.

Comment: @DaveNewton - you're gonna love Perl6 (they went the same way as Ruby/Python and made everything an object)

Answer (score 7):

You can use List [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method to check whether the string is present or not in the list:

public boolean contains(Object o)

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
>   element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

Simply use it like this:

```
myList.contains(searchString);
```

Comment: The method belongs to `List` interface (in fact, it belongs to `Collection`). Note that OP doesn't know much about methods on Java classes but at least know about programmming to interfaces instead of class implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`Collection#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method, since `List` inherits this method from `Collection` interface. From its Javadoc:

> `boolean contains(Object o)`
>
> Returns `true` if this collection contains the specified element. More formally, returns `true` if and only if this collection contains at least one element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

It is very simple to use:

```
String searchString = "abc";
List<String> myList = .... //create the list as you want/need
if (myList.contains(searchString)) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Note that this won't support a insensitive search i.e. you can have `"abc"` in the list but doesn't mean you will get the same if seeking for `"aBc"`. If you want/need this, you will have to write your own method and use an iterator.